# Angular add watch to directive's link function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to track for changes inside a directive to 'current_step' variable;

My directive:

```
function wizardStepsCircle(logger) {
        var directive = {
            bindToController: true,
            controller: WizardStepsCircleController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'wizard-steps-circle.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                current_step: '@'
            },
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('current_step', function (newvalue) {
                logger.info('current_step is:', newvalue);
           });           
        }
    }
```

Directive's Controller:

```
function WizardStepsCircleController() {
        var vm = this;      

        activate();

        function activate() {
            vm.c_step = current_step;
        }
    }
```

Directive's HTML:

```
 <wizard-steps-circle current_step="{{vm.WzrdCtrls.c_step}}"></wizard-steps-circle>
```

1. How to access 'current_step' from the controller?
2. 'vm.WzrdCtrls.c_step' is changing but $observe is not fired. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: c_step="{{vm.WzrdCtrls.c_step}}" you assign a variable to itself?

Comment: You need to decide if you want to call it c_step or current_step.

Comment: after the edit, you still assign a variable to itself. it's infinite: a = b = a;

Comment: I think you should place watch on `vm.current_step`, as you are using `controllerAs` with `bindToController: true`

Comment: kobi, gever, vm.WzrdCtrls.c_step is taken from parent scope, so its all good there.... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
 attrs.$observe('current_step', function (newvalue) {
            logger.info('current_step is:', newvalue);
       });
```

to:

```
 attrs.$observe('currentStep', function (newvalue) {
            logger.info('current_step is:', newvalue);
       });
```

Read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) in section **Normalization** more about this

Comment: that worked! using 'current_step' is not working. Had to change it to currentStep. How do I access 'currentStep' from inside the Controlle? Should I pass $scope?

Comment: Here is a working Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/PlqrPqOc6tCIvAXtIAGX?p=preview how to add a watcher and track all changes in the controller. If you decide to use this approach, $observe in the link function is not necessary anymore

Answer (score 0):

**Check if this is watch you want**

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope,$http){
var vm = this;
$scope.current_step = 10;

}).directive('wizardStepsCircle',wizardStepsCircle);
function wizardStepsCircle() {
        var directive = {
            bindToController: true,
            controller: WizardStepsCircleController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',

            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                current_step: '@cStep'
            },
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log(scope,element);
            attrs.$observe('cStep', function (newvalue) {
                console.log('cStep:', newvalue);
           });      
          scope.$watch('current_step', function (newvalue) {
                console.log('current_step:', newvalue);
           }); 
        }
    }

function WizardStepsCircleController($scope) {
        var vm = this;      
     console.log("CSCSCS"+$scope.current_step,$scope);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="current_step">
 <wizard-steps-circle c_step="{{current_step}}"></wizard-steps-circle>
</div>
```